# Android - Checking if a twitch stream is online

Tags: java, android, json

How can i check if a twitch stream is online in android?
When i get on the url "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/erenjjing", it shows {"error":"Bad Request","status":400,"message":"No client id specified"}
So i can't parse it.

Comment: Is there an API?  If not, you could try sniffing the stream from a proper client and emulating that.

Comment: https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/is-streamer-online-json-help-users-zigenzag-follows/946

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your client_id. 
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/erenjjing?client_id=xxx

To get the client id go to https://www.twitch.tv/settings/connections and scroll down.